# how to check if data is already in html table using firebase real time database?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, html-table

I have a live listener on my database data in my HTML table that is generated by javascript and when I add a new entry or delete an old entry, the data that was previously in the table gets duplicated.

```
var database = firebase.database().ref().child('transactions');
            database.on('value', function(snapshot){
                if(snapshot.exists()){
                    var content = '';
                    snapshot.forEach(function(data){
                        var CustomerName = data.val().CustomerName;
                        var AmountSent = data.val().AmountSent;
                        var TimeEffected= data.val().TimeEffected;
                        var DateEffected = data.val().DateEffected;
                        var Successful = data.val().Successful;

                        content += '<tr>';
                        content += '<td>' + CustomerName + '</td>';//column2
                        content += '<td>' + AmountSent + '</td>'; //column1 
                        content += '<td>' + TimeEffected + '</td>'; //column1 
                        content += '<td>' + DateEffected + '</td>'; //column1
                        content += '<td>' + Successful + '</td>'; //column1
                        content += '</tr>';
                    });
                    $('#ex-table').append(content);
```

When it 'was database.once' and I had a refresh button I wouldn't get the data duplicated but I've changed it to'database.on' and now the data in the table duplicates whenever I do anything to the database.

I'm looking for the most cost-effective way.
I'm not sure which one of both 'database.once' or 'database.on' save money.

Comment: That kinds depends on how often the user wants to attempt to refresh the data (is it more often than the data actually changes?), and if you have disk persistence enabled, which would cache data until it changes on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you listen to the `value` event on `transactions`, each time your callback is called the snapshot will contain all data under `transactions`. So any data that wasn't changed will also be in the snapshot, leading to it being in your table multiple times.

I see two options:

1. Wipe the table each time you get updated data
2. Perform more fine-grained updates

#### Wipe the table each time you get updated data

This is the simplest, since it requires the fewest changes to your existing code. Just clear the contents from the table whenever you get updated data from the database:

```
var database = firebase.database().ref().child('transactions');
database.on('value', function(snapshot){
    $('#ex-table').empty(); // clear existing contents
    if(snapshot.exists()){
        var content = '';
        snapshot.forEach(function(data){
            var CustomerName = data.val().CustomerName;
            var AmountSent = data.val().AmountSent;
            var TimeEffected= data.val().TimeEffected;
            var DateEffected = data.val().DateEffected;
            var Successful = data.val().Successful;

            content += '<tr>';
            content += '<td>' + CustomerName + '</td>';//column2
            content += '<td>' + AmountSent + '</td>'; //column1 
            content += '<td>' + TimeEffected + '</td>'; //column1 
            content += '<td>' + DateEffected + '</td>'; //column1
            content += '<td>' + Successful + '</td>'; //column1
            content += '</tr>';
        });
        $('#ex-table').append(content);
```

This should work fine, but repaints the entire table contents every time anything in there changes. This may result in noticeable flicker when the table is large.

#### Perform more fine-grained updates

The alternative is to perform more fine-grained updates. I.e. initially you add all children, after that you only add the new children, remove any data that gets removed from the database, etc.

Firebase has specific events for this purpose, which fire one level lower in the database. For example, the `child_added` event is defined as "fires initially for each node under the reference, and then each time a node is added under the reference". In the same vein there are `child_removed`, `child_changed` and `child_moved` events. With these events you can perform more granular updates to the table.

For example, here's how you'd handle `child_added`:

```
var database = firebase.database().ref().child('transactions');
database.on('child_added', function(snapshot){
    var data = snapshot.val();

    var content = '<tr id="'+snapshot.key+'">';
    content += '<td>' + data.CustomerName + '</td>';
    content += '<td>' + data.AmountSent + '</td>';
    content += '<td>' + data.TimeEffected + '</td>';
    content += '<td>' + data.DateEffected + '</td>';
    content += '<td>' + data.Successful + '</td>';
    content += '</tr>';

    $('#ex-table').append(content);
});
```

Aside from cleaning up the code a bit, I also add the `snapshot.key` to the `tr`. This allows you to later look up the row for a key, just in case you get a `child_changed`, or `child_removed` event.

For example, here's how to remove the row from the table when it gets removed from the database:

```
database.on('child_removed', function(snapshot){
    $('#'+snapshot.key).remove()
});
```

Comment: I used the perform more fine-grained updates method. I'm guessing it doesn't affect my usage as much as the first method, right...? Also, I've been trying to add the child_changed method, it's not working. How would I do this and is this method more efficient than the first?

Comment: If the performance of the first method is fine for you, go for it. I'm not sure what you were trying to do with `child_changed`, so it's hard to comment what you were doing wrong there. If you need more help, post the [minimal standalone code that reproduces where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with that.

Comment: I am trying to now let the table observe for changed details. So once something has been changed in database, change on table. @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: Ah OK. If you post the code you tried, I can have a look. It probably makes most sense to post as a new question, linked to this one for context.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54278177/how-to-make-edited-values-in-firebase-real-time-database-show-up-in-html-table @FrankvanPuffelen